# Is it possible to add taxonomy filters to the standard advanced search?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, search

I wonder if is possible to add select boxes from my taxonomy to the standard Drupal 7 advanced search form. I'd like to search for document containing the word "test" and which have the word "High" in the vocabulary "Height".

Comment: Actually, it is not possible because D7 removed that option. There also is no module that does the job. The solution is to create a view with every filter you need, including the text to search for.

Comment: are you talking about [Views Search](http://drupal.org/project/views_search) because it's not yet available for D7 :(